# How to setup angularjs in a different file in DNN 8.0 SPA framework?

Tags: angularjs, dotnetnuke

I'm developing in DNN 8.0 with its new SPA framework.

I'm using angularjs instead of the defaulted KnockOut.

When I put module setup code in view.html, it works fine. But it doesn't work if I try to put the code in a different file, say app.js. Anyone has seen this before?

A snap shot of the view.html that works looks like this:

```
[JavaScript:{ jsname: "JQuery" }]
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/Resources/Shared/scripts/dnn.jquery.js"}]
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/DNNSPA/Scripts/angular.js"}]
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/MyApp/Scripts/angular-route.js"}]
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/MyApp/ngApp/app.js"}]
[JavaScript:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/MyApp/ngApp/ngControllers/FirstController.js"}]

[CSS:{ path: "~/DesktopModules/MyApp/CSS/bootstrap.min.css"}]


<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var moduleId = parseInt("[ModuleContext:ModuleId]");
    var portalId = parseInt("[ModuleContext:PortalId]");
    var sf = $.ServicesFramework(moduleId);
    var moduleName = "MyApp";
    if ("[ModuleContext:EditMode]" === 'True') {
        var editMode = true;
    }
    console.log(editMode);
    var currentDate = d;

    var app = angular
    .module('dnnapp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
    .config(
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/DesktopModules/MyApp/partials/firstView.html',
                controller: 'firstController'
            });
        });

    app.controller('firstController', function ($scope, $http) {
        // controller code
    });

</script>

<div class="module-wrap" ng-view>
</div>
```

All setup code is in view.html.

But if I move the module definition to app.js and controller definition to FirstController.js, it doesn't work.

I've seen others make it work in different files, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The SPA tokens, ie: [ModuleContext:ModuleId] will not get replaced in your .js file.  Therefore you need to do some setup work for your angular module on the page and move all the rest to a js file.  Here is one technique:

On your View.html, define an html element for your angular app with an ng-init() method:

```
<div id='dnnuclear-item-[ModuleContext:ModuleId]' ng-controller="ItemController" 
    ng-init="init([ModuleContext:ModuleId],'[ModuleContext:ModuleName]','[ModuleContext:EditMode]')"> 

  ... 

</div>
```

Also on your View.html, bootstrap your angular app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var moduleContainer = document.getElementById('dnnuclear-item-[ModuleContext:ModuleId]');
        angular.bootstrap(moduleContainer, ["dnnuclear.ItemApp"]);
    });
</script>
```

Then in your .js file, define the angular module and controller with the init method implementation:

```
var dnnuclear = dnnuclear || {};

dnnuclear.ItemApp = angular.module("dnnuclear.ItemApp", ['ngDialog']);

dnnuclear.ItemApp.controller("ItemController", function ($scope, $window, $log, ngDialog, dnnServiceClient) { 

... 

     $scope.init = function (moduleId, moduleName, editable) {
        $scope.ModuleId = moduleId;
        $scope.EditMode = editable;
        dnnServiceClient.init(moduleId, moduleName);
        $scope.getAll();
    }
}
```

If you need to pass more information to the module than a few variables, I would recommend changing this approach.  I have more on this in my DNNHero.com tutorial, [Advanced Angular Concepts](http://www.dnnhero.com/video/advanced-angular-concepts-for-dnn-introduction-and-demonstration-of-module).

Comment: I believe your approach will work. But I don't need to use the module id as part of the controller name - there will be only one of this module on a page. The question is, why it stops working when I put code in a different js file?

Comment: Are you putting the SPA tokens in the js file?  The first part of my response mentioned the issue there.  Which is why I explained using the init() method of the controller to pass that in from the View.html

Comment: I ended up using Jquery to pass in the moduleId. But the point is that we need to pass moduleId to the js files. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: how does this handle having multiple modules on the same page? you are still calling angular.module("dnnuclear.ItemApp",[]) rather than angular.module("dnnuclear.ItemApp-MODULEID",[])  so how would this work? I can;t think of any way without the SPA tokens being available in all JS files for a module

Answer (score -3):

You should try the AngularDNN module. It will probably save your time. It can be found here:
http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/angulardnn

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.